# How can I make herbs easy to remove from a Crock-Pot?

Tags: spices, soup, crockpot

I made a soup in a Crock-Pot and placed rosemary directly in it. Once the soup was finished the rosemary had dispersed all over the soup.

The process I used:

Lightly spray Crock-Pot with Pam
Cut up vegetables (onion,carrot,garlic,cabbage,potato,etc)
Cut up and trim chicken breast
Place ingredients in Crock-Pot
Add chicken stock
Add in rosemary (on the stick not ground)
Add in bay leaves and a few other spices
Cook on low for 8 hours

So the soup turned out pretty good, except that it had the bay leaves and the rosemary leaves scattered throughout.

How am I supposed to add in fresh spices (not ground ones) such as the rosemary stick while being able to remove them from the Crock-Pot once the cooking process is complete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for what is called a *[bouquet garni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouquet_garni)* which is essentially a bundle of herbs tied together for easy removal.

There are three basic ways to do it:

- For herbs like thyme or sage which are on twigs, simply tie together the twigs with some food-safe string.
- Wrap the bundle of herbs in cheese cloth, and and tie together
- Use a tea ball type device to hold the herbs.

When the dish is done cooking, you can then remove the herbs all in one go simply by removing the bouqet garni.

Comment: I think I will go with the cheese cloth approach. Thanks :)

Comment: "tea infuser ball"

Comment: @Optionparty I am a coffee guy :-)